# How can I take either two or one integer as input on the same line in Java?

Tags: java, input, io, java.util.scanner

For example, how can I take the either values `1 0` or just the value `2` to then be used at a latter part of the program. Say that `1` adds the number `0` to a list and `2` prints out a phrase. Right now I only know how to take two numbers on the same line using

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); // receives input for x y
int x = Integer.parseInt(sc.next());
int y = Integer.parseInt(sc.next());
```

Comment: Note: [You don't need to say thanks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Comment: and [don't need to say that it is in Java in the title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles) - with the [tag:java] tag the system automatically do it.

Comment: `String line = sc.nextLine(); // <-- takes either one or two or three or none; however many are on one line.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put spaces between terms:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int[] values = new int[2];
String[] arguments = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
for(int i = 0; i < arguments.length && i < values.length; i++){
    values[i] = Integer.parseInt(arguments[i]);
}
scanner.close();
```

On line 2 you specify maximum inputs

On line 3 in the "" you can specify what goes between terms

On line 2 & 5 you can specify term type

Answer (score 1):

Just adding to `@Devon Rutledge`'s answer, that Scanner class separates tokens (in this case, numbers) on the condition that there are 1 or more spaces between them.

Hence, as Devon mentioned above, you should add spaces between the inputs.

However, the answer posted above works the exact same way as a normal `sc.next()` would, albeit with a problem that if you enter two spaces between inputs, it will five an error. So there's no problem with your code, per se, but just the inputs.

If you **do** want to accept single-digit numbers without spaces, then you can try this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
sc.useDelimiter("");
int x = sc.nextInt();
int y = sc.nextInt();
```

Also, it is better to use `sc.nextInt()`, as `sc.next()` would accept even the letters, which cannot not be converted to `int`.